# Enable user namespaces in Debian kernel

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I'm trying to figure out how to enable user namespaces capability in my kernel (I think CAP_SYS_USER_NS).  I'm using Debian Stretch, kernel 4.6.0-1-amd64.

My assumption is there is a way to turn on user namespaces and recompile the kernel.  After some hours searching, I can find a post of doing this in Ubuntu (https://blog.tutum.co/2013/12/14/enabling-the-user-namespace-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/) but not Debian (problem may be I'm on the wrong track and so my searches are off base).

My end game is to enable these in order to keep up with Docker and Google sandboxing which apparently require user namespaces to be enabled in the kernel (e.g., my Chrome containers no longer work).

Comment: See also the same question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303213/4319

Answer (score 46):

On Debian the ability to create or handle [user namespaces](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7) from a non-privileged process (usually meaning non-root user) is disabled by default.
There's a Debian-specific patch ([from Ubuntu](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/serge/ubuntu-saucy.git/commit/?id=5c847404dcb2e3195ad0057877e1422ae90892b8)) to the kernel that adds the  sysctl knob `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone` (with a default value of 0 meaning *disabled*).

To enable it (until next reboot),

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

For a permanent configuration, you can add a new entry in [`/etc/sysctl.d`](https://manpages.debian.org/procps/sysctl.conf.5) to enable the feature at boot:

```
echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
service procps restart
```

---

This patch predates (by three years) the sysctl `user.max_user_namespaces` (initially `userns.max_user_namespaces`) which can be set to 0 to achieve the same result. It was probably kept around  for (Debian) compatibility reasons: expecting the feature disabled by default.

From the [initial commit message](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/serge/ubuntu-saucy.git/commit/?id=5c847404dcb2e3195ad0057877e1422ae90892b8), it was created (in 2013) as a temporary measure when there were some doubts about the security implications related to using user namespaces:

> add sysctl to disallow unprivileged CLONE_NEWUSER by default
>
> This is a short-term patch. Unprivileged use of CLONE_NEWUSER is
> certainly an intended feature of user namespaces. However for at
> least saucy we want to make sure that, if any security issues are
> found, we have a fail-safe.

Comment: This still works on Stretch, kernel `4.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.6-3 (2017-01-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Is there a reason why it's disabled by default in Debian?

Comment: Historically the security of user namespace was uncertain. eg: https://lwn.net/Articles/673597/ . If a user, as root inside her own namespace can trick the kernel into allowing an operation on the real host, there's privilege escalation. Usual non-user namespaces require explicit root (so admin) permission and so run what the admin chose: that's a known risk. A later mechanism was added in vanilla kernel: user.max_user_namespaces . When set to 0 user namespaces are disabled. The Debian (actually from Ubuntu) patch is still around, even if probably obsolete. Maybe for compatibility reasons

Comment: `/proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone` doesn't exist on my Debian testing/buster install. What kernel config does this require? I'm on kernel 4.18.3.

Comment: Kernel 4.18.3 hasn't been released on Debian yet, so your kernel is not a Debian testing's kernel. You can ignore this parameter entirely (until you install an actual kernel from Debian). Also look at my previous comment about user.max_user_namespaces

Comment: I'm compiling my own kernel - that's why it's newer than Debian's release. Also, I found the kernel config option, it's called `CONFIG_USER_NS`.

Comment: This fix works for manjaro/arch with kernel 4.14

Comment: Indeed the same patch is applied by Manjaro ( https://gitlab.manjaro.org/packages/core/linux414/blob/master/0001-add-sysctl-to-disallow-unprivileged-CLONE_NEWUSER-by.patch )

Comment: Or simply : `sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou nice but where do you add this to as a default startup parameter. I'm running MX Linux. maybe I'd better check their docs

Comment: @Slabo well... it's written in my answer ("permanent solution"). SkippyleGrandGourou wrote the equivalent command involved when the configuration file is read, which is better than echo (avoids shell problems with sudo)

Comment: As for ALT Linux distros (there, it's different from Debian), see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303214/4319 ; it's: `sysctl -w kernel.userns_restrict=0`